# Pandas add new column with groupby based on values in 3 different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
    Document    Date    Schedule    Quantity    Key
0   123      2020-12-02    1          20         1
1   123      2020-12-02    2          10         0
2   123      2020-12-02    3           5         0
3   456      2020-12-02    4          10         0
```

I want to add a new column: grouped by Document and Date, if the quantity in row 0 (where Key = 1) is different from the quantity in the column with the lowest value in schedule (excluding row 0) and where key = 0, New_Col = 1. If quantities are the same, New_Col = 0.

Desired output:

```
    Document    Date    Schedule    Quantity    Key   New_Col
0   123      2020-12-02    1          20         1       1
1   123      2020-12-02    2          10         0       0
2   123      2020-12-02    3           5         0       0
3   456      2020-12-02    4          10         0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the following function:

```
def getNewCol(grp):
    rv = pd.Series(0, index=grp.index)
    # Quantity from row with Key == 1 (a Series)
    qn = grp.query('Key == 1').Quantity
    if qn.size == 0:   # Nothing found
        return rv
    qnK1 = qn.iloc[0]  # The Quantity itself
    # Min Schedule from "other" rows
    schMin = grp.query('Key != 1').Schedule.min()
    # Quantity from this row
    qnMin = grp.query('Schedule == @schMin').Quantity.iloc[0]
    if qnK1 != qnMin:  # Different
        rv.iloc[0] = 1 # Set the first element of the result
    return rv
```

Then apply it and save the result in a new column:

```
df['New_Col'] = df.groupby(['Document', 'Date'], as_index=False)\
    .apply(getNewCol).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

The result is:

```
   Document       Date  Schedule  Quantity  Key  New_Col
0       123 2020-12-02         1        20    1        1
1       123 2020-12-02         2        10    0        0
2       123 2020-12-02         3         5    0        0
3       456 2020-12-02         4        10    0        0
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it is not working. It's giving me a New_Col = 1 only for the unique combinations of Document & Date. I would like to see New_Col = 1 everytime the following row has same document, same date, schedule +1 from previous row, different quantity from previous row and key = 0

Comment: Indeed, I missed the detail that you want to find a row with *lowest value in Schedule* (from "other" rows) and from this row take *Quantity* to compare. Now I corrected the solution and added some comments.